# How to diagnose external USB3.1->PCIe enclosure?

Tags: usb, ssd, external-hard-drive, pci-express

Bought a new blank PCIe SSD and an external enclosure (it is going to replace the internal PCIe SSD of a notebook). However after plugging it in the drive does not show up, even in disk tool programs.

Let me reiterate: the drive is new from Amazon and has never been formatted.

How do I diagnose whether it's the drive (or whatever the proper term is for these memory-chips-on-a-board) or the enclosure?

EDIT 1: [This enclosure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MS240DQ) holding [This drive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M20VBU7)

EDIT 2: It plays the "device connected" sound when plugged in and the little blue light goes on, but that seems to just indicate power. On Mac OS X, USB status shows the enclosure but with only 3 sub-devices, my other external enclosure (SATA mechanical hard drive) shows 5 sub-devices. Still need to try it on Windows.

Comment: What make and model is the enclosure? If possible, please provide a link.

Comment: You didn't say which OS you have. First check if the USB device appears at all (`lsusb` under Linux). Next step is to verify that the USB device has the proper drivers, and then see if the drivers offer any diagnostic output.

Comment: @DanielB see my edit

Comment: @dirkt  See my edit. Why would it require any drivers other than the OS's mass storage? How do I actually do this?

Comment: @Snowbody - See my answer.  Your adapter doesn't support M.2 PCIe SSDs  and is not compatible with the drive you purchased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you purchased is not compatible with your SSD.

You purchased a PCIe 3.0 M.2 drive.

> M.2 (2280) - PCIe 3.0 x4 NVM Express SSD for Client PCs

[Samsung 960 EVO Series - 500GB NVMe - M.2 Internal SSD (MZ-V6E500BW)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M20VBU7)

The adapter you purchased does not support PCIe based M2 SSDs.

> Note: Fit for B Key only, not support M key. It does NOT support PCI-E
>   based B key & any M key SSD

[USB 3.1 Type C to M.2 NGFF (B & M Key) Key B Adapter SSD Hard Disk Box Enclosure Case for M.2 NGFF SATA-Based B & M Key 2280 SSD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MS240DQ)

> How do I diagnose whether it's the drive (or whatever the proper term
>   is for these memory-chips-on-a-board) or the enclosure?

There isn't anything wrong with the drive.  The adapter doesn't support the drive you purchased.

> ### Unavailable SSD models E.g:
>
> - **Samsung MZ-V6E250BW 960EVO 250G M.2**
> - Samsung SM961 NVME PCIE M.2SSD 256
> - Samsung MZ-V5P512BW 950PRO M.2 512G SSD

Considering the MZ-V6E250BW is not compatible with the adapter it means the MZ-V6E500BW is not compatible.

Comment: Silly me thinking a PCIe SSD was the same as a PCIe SSD. Sometimes I just can't see the obvious unless it's pointed out to me. Thanks.

Comment: @Snowbody, these are not "PCIe" SSDs. These are **"M.2 SSDs"**. The M.2 itself has many flavors, eight or something. The SSDs can come in two flavors, with SATA connection, or with PCIe connection, both included into M.2 connector. However, not all interfaces have to be supported by silicon controllers, that's where confusion occurs. Your enclosure supports only the SATA-flavor, while Samsung 950/960 series  looks like are having PCIe interface only.